# How Javascript library break_Infinity.js are able to represent incredibly big numbers

Tags: javascript

(Sorry for grammar mistakes, english isn't my first language) So, I'm making a game, and it's centered around having big numbers, as you might guess, i use library that you already read in the title. But i wonder, how it able to get on so many orders of magnitude? I mean, i understand how floating point number type are able to reach number 1.797e308, but how exactly break_infinity.js are able to reach such big numbers. Did it just uses more bits? Did it uses just an array, for an example, {2, 555} which represents number 2e555? Are it does something totally different?

I read an entire github page. Nothing but brag about how it is faster than decimal.js. I read entire documentation. Incredible amount of commands, but not a single word about how it represents such large numbers. I tried google search. Also nothing.

Addressing few comments:
Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans- Yes, JS has type of number that can be bigger than 2e53, but this type of number prioritizes accuracy over speed, which is not so convenient for a person, who goes for numbers much, much larger than that.

Pointy- the source code for this library is mostly written in typescript and has functions, that i don't quite understand and honestly, i tried, but after few hours i dropped trying to understand it.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: JS has BigInt [built in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). There is no reason to use a third party library if you just need "huge numbers".

Comment: You can look at the source code.